# How do I input a string into an object (Array array) for a linked list add method?

Tags: java

I am currently programming my finale  for my Computer Science 3 class and I need to write a Object LinkedList tester class (in this case a tester ActorLinkedList.java called ListTeset.java) and one fot he requirements is to write an add method that adds an Actor object at the beginning of the list. But when attempting to add an Actor objects name (a string) to it shows an incompatible types error.

I have attempted to place it in a seperate object containing a string, and using the .setName() but couldnt properly create the connection and resulted in an error.

```
public class Actor {

    String name;
    Actor next;

    Actor(){
        next = null;
        name = null;
    }

    Actor (String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.next = null;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    void setName (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    Actor getNextPtr(){
        return this.next;
    }

    void setNextPtr(Actor next){

        this.next = next;

    }
    @Override
       public String toString(){

           return "\nActor{ name = " + name  + '}';


       }


}
//-------------------------
public class ActorLinkedList {
    Actor head;

    int count;

    ActorLinkedList(){
        head = null;
    }

    public ActorLinkedList(Actor head, int count) {
        this.head = head;
        this.count = count;
    }

    void add(Actor actor){

        Actor add = new Actor();

        add.next = head;

        head = add;
    }

    Actor get(int index){
        int i;
        Actor current;

        current = head;

        for(i = 0; i  < count; i++){

            if(i == index-1)
                return(current);

            if(current == null)
                return(null);

            current = current.getNextPtr();

        }
        return null;
    }

    int size(){ return count; }


}
//----------------
public class ListTester {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        ActorLinkedList list = new ActorLinkedList();

        Actor act1 = "Bradly Madly";

        list.add(act1);


    }

}
```

It is supposed to input an Actor objects name into the linkedList but results in incompatible types.

Comment: How are you assigning a string to your own custom object actor?Is it not giving a compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create objects of a class you need to use the constructor that you have defined in the class i.e.

```
Actor act1 = new Actor("Bradly Madly");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to create the Actor object properly
in the ListTester class 
Actor act1 = "Bradly Madly";//this is wrong
you are trying to assign string value to Actor object this is causing type mismatch you need to create the actor object properly check the below code you can use any one step
step 1)
  Actor act1 = new Actor("Bradly Madly");
          **OR**
step 2) Actor act1= new Actor();
act1.setName("Bradly Madly");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, we should create an object with keyword 'new' unlike in C++. Then load the constructor which will initialize the memory allocated because of new Keyword